# How to execute a one off S3 data transfer using BigQuery command line tool?

Tags: google-bigquery

Transfers from [S3 to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/s3-transfer) works properly if you use the console. On the command line I have also everything working just there is one parameter that I can't find how to configure.

On the console UI you have "Schedule Options" and you could set the repeat as "on demand":
[image]

However on the command line I can't find a way to set the transfer as "on demand". Do you know which parameter do I need to pass to set it as on demand? it automatically set a schedule of every 24 hours.

Example run:

```
bq mk --transfer_config \
--target_dataset=my_dataset \
--display_name="my_transfer" \
--params='{"data_path":"s3://my_bucket/my_path*",
"destination_table_name_template":"testing",
"file_format":"CSV",
"max_bad_records":"1",
"ignore_unknown_values":"true",
"field_delimiter":";",
"skip_leading_rows":"0",
"allow_quoted_newlines":"false",
"allow_jagged_rows":"false",
"access_key_id": "",
"secret_access_key": ""}' \
--data_source=amazon_s3
#how can I setup the schedule options as on demand?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `disableAutoScheduling` parameter to false in the DTS API.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs#TransferConfig.ScheduleOptions

For example:

```
{
   "dataSourceId":"google_cloud_storage",
   "displayName":"bar",
   "params":{
      "destination_table_name_template":"bart",
      "data_path_template":"gs://fuzzy-wuzzy/wiki_1M.csv",
      "write_disposition":"APPEND",
      "file_format":"CSV",
      "max_bad_records":"0",
      "field_delimiter":",",
      "skip_leading_rows":"0"
   },
   "emailPreferences":{
      "enableFailureEmail":false
   },
   "notificationPubsubTopic":null,
   "destinationDatasetId":"another_test",
   "schedule":"",
   "scheduleOptions":{
      "disableAutoScheduling":true
   }
}
```

To do this via the BigQuery CLI tool, you need to use the `no_auto_scheduling` flag.

[image]